# ZF2 - set and get params from route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have following route in my module config:

```
/home[/:action][/:id][/:page][/:service][/:sort]
```

When I try to skip some params, like page and/or service, and just pass sort variable, it is beeing set as page. That route works perfecly fine:

home/index/1/1

and I get:

```
action = index
page = 1
service = 1
```

but when I skip some params, and want only pass action and sort:

home/index/asc

I get:

```
action = index
page = asc
```

I create my link like this:

```
$this->url(null, array('sort' => $sort), array(), true);
```

Is there any proper way to do it correctly and as I want?

In ZF that was much easier, because it was url like: index/sort/asc etc. key of param and it's value. Is it possible to achieve in ZF2?

Comment: $this->url('name_of_your_route', array('sort' => $sort), array(), true);

Comment: @Chu Khanh Van: Nope. Last param - true - gives the route name.

Comment: Good practice to always include the route name in my opinion, however that's not the issue here. Do you have any constraints on your route params in the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using optional params in route they need to have a name or be inclosed inside another optional param :

```
'/home[/:action[/id/:id][/page/:page][/service/:service][/sort/:sort]]'
```